# Why does this plot not update ? (matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib

Code below, I want to write a code that updates its function by cearing the axes and assigning new plots. It works when I only have one plot, but doesnt when I use subplots()...

Thanks

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig , ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
alpha = 0.70

def sin(x):
    return np.sin(alpha*x)

def lin(x):
    return alpha*x

for i in range(5):
    ax[0].clear()
    ax[1].clear()
    ax[0].plot(x,lin(x), marker='o', label = str(i))
    ax[1].plot(x,sin(x), marker='o')
    fig.legend()
    plt.show()
    alpha = alpha**2
    time.sleep(0.5)
```